# Include Entity navigation properties using a Service Reference

Tags: entity-framework-6, odata, wcf-data-services, service-reference, navigation-properties

I am using a **WCF Data Services** class that exposes an entity framework model via the **OData** protocol like so:

```
public class Service : EntityFrameworkDataService<MyEntities>
{
    public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
    {
        config.UseVerboseErrors = true;
        config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("*", EntitySetRights.All);
        config.SetServiceOperationAccessRule("*", ServiceOperationRights.All);
        config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V3;
    }
}
```

I consume this service through a **service reference** in a web solution. I am having problems **including** all the **navigation properties** for the entity. I cannot use the following syntax because I do not know what type of entity the user may be requesting:

***I CANNOT USE***

```
MyEntities.Customer.Expand("Address");
```

or

```
MyEntities.Customer.Include("Address");
```

What I am currently doing is building a URI string with the $expand=Entity1,Entity2 syntax and then executing that against my service as follows:

```
    public static QueryOperationResponse<object> GetList(string entitySetName, params string[] preloads)
    {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        string queryString = string.Empty;
        object result = null;
        Uri dataAccessURI;

        stringBuilder.Append(ServiceReferenceURI.AbsoluteUri);
        stringBuilder.Append(entitySetName);

        if (preloads != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= preloads.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                queryString = i == 0 ? "?$expand=" : ",";
                stringBuilder.AppendFormat("{0}{1}", queryString, preloads[i]);
            }
        }

        dataAccessURI = new Uri(stringBuilder.ToString());

        try
        {
            result = TitanEntities.Execute<object>(dataAccessURI, "GET", true);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // log any errors to the console
            WriteConsoleMessage(ex.Message, DataAccessEventType.Error);
        }

        return (QueryOperationResponse<object>)result;
```

resulting URI string is similar to this:

```
http://192.168.0.196/Service.svc/AliquotPreparation?$expand=Aliquot,AliquotPrepBatch,AnalysisPreparationMethod,Unit,Employee,Unit,PreparationMethod,State
```

To me this is a crappy implementation. It is all I could come up with right now though. The problem is, if there are A LOT of navigation properties the $expand command gets too long and the URI reaches it's character limit!

So how can I implement this through a service reference? I would greatly appreciate someone's help!!!

Comment: If you know the entity type (e.g., `Customer`), then you can invoke `DataServiceQuery<TEntity>.Expand` using reflection.

Comment: unfortunately I do not know the type. The only information I have is the string name of the entity.